# kernel matrix with trivial solution only

Tags: linear-algebra

When a matrix have only the trivial solution (zero vertor). How i must represent the solve?

For a particular case of matix 4x3
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 & -3 \\
  0 & 2 & 1 \\
  1 & 2 & 1 \\
  1 & -1 & -4
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

After do some operations get its reduced form. 
(R3-R1, R4-R1), (R4+R2, R2-2R3), (-R2/7), (R1+3R2, R3-4R2), (R1-R3), (R3<->R2)
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
With\ Rank(A) = 3
$$

I found diferent cases for the solve

1. First (I think is wrong)

$$
ker(A) = A\vec{x} = \nexists
$$

1. Second

$$
ker(A) = A\vec{x} = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

For the rank theorem
$$
nul(A) = dim(ker(A)) = n - rank(A)= 3 - 3 = 0
$$

In adition, this solution satisfy the properies of a subspace:

- Contains the null element of the space
- Closed under the sum of element and scalar product

Any idea what is the right solve?

Comment: if ${\rm rank}A=3$ it means that you have an injective linear map $\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^4$

Comment: The vector space $\{0\}$ is a perfectly valid kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The rank theorem is optimal.

Otherwise just solve it like you would with any other numbers:

if the vectors are represented by $x, y, z$, then your system becomes

$$x = 0; y = 0; z = 0; 0=0$$ which has as unique solution the null vector.